# Avoid repeating as_tibble() in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, tibble

Currently, I'm using multiple `as_tibble(a_matrix)` commands in my last line of code. To avoid repeating this command, what would be the shortest alternative?

```
(T1 = matrix(c(2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5), 4, 2))      
colnames(T1) <- c("y1", "y2")

(T2 = matrix(c(4:6, 8, 6, 7), 3, 2))      
colnames(T2) <- colnames(T1) 

(T3 = matrix(c(7, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6), 5, 2))      
colnames(T3) <- colnames(T1) 

# bind rows of T1,T2 & T3 score matricies for the 3 groups:
(dat <- bind_rows(as_tibble(T1), as_tibble(T2), as_tibble(T3), .id = "group"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the matrix in a list and convert it into a tibble using `map` command.

```
list_df <- list(T1, T2, T3)
dat <- purrr::map_df(list_df, as_tibble, .id = 'group')
dat

#   group y1 y2
#1      1  2  3
#2      1  3  4
#3      1  5  4
#4      1  2  5
#5      2  4  8
#6      2  5  6
#7      2  6  7
#8      3  7  6
#9      3  8  7
#10     3 10  8
#11     3  9  5
#12     3  7  6
```

Comment: `list_df <- mget(paste0('T', 1:3))` however, that would give group values as `T1`, `T2` and `T3`. You can change it to 1, 2, 3 by removing `'T'` from them using `sub`.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
list_df <- list(T1, T2, T3) 
rbindlist(lapply(list_df, as.data.frame), idcol = 'group')
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lst1 <- mget(str_c('T', 1:3))
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, group = seq_along(lst1), lst1))
```

and apply the `as_tibble` once

```
as_tibble(out)
```